# Skip execution of a line using Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am using mockito for unit testing and I want to skip a line.

```
// method I am testing
public String doSomeTask(String src, String dst) {
    // some code

    utils.createLink(src,dst);

    // some more code
} 


// utils class
public void createLink(String src, String dst) {
    // do something
    Path realSrc = "/tmp/" + src;
    Files.createSymbolicLink(realSrc, dst);

    // do something
}


// Test class

@Mock
private Utils utils;

@Test
public void testDoSomeTask() {
    // this does not seem to work, it is still executing the createLink method
    doNothing.when(utils).createLink(anyString(), anyString());
    myClass.doSomeTask(anyString(), anyString());
}
```

Now, `createLink` is a void method and its failing during my testing with exception reason `AccessDenied` to create a directory.

I want to skip the line `utils.createLink(src,dst);` and continue with next lines. Is there a way I can tell Mockito to do this ?

Comment: https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.25.1/org/mockito/Mockito.html#do_family_methods_stubs

Comment: How is *utils* variable instantiated?

Comment: You can mock `utils.createLink()` method and make it empty. It will still be executed, but won't perform anything.

Comment: @GonzaloMatheu `Utils utils = new Utils();`

Comment: @PavelSmirnov how can I do that ?

Comment: @Logic, provided an example in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `utils` variable can be set with a setter, you can spy on your `Utils` class object and override its `createLink()` method.

The basic idea is:

```
Utils utils = new Utils();
Utils spyUtils = Mockito.spy(utils);
doNothing().when(spyUtils).createLink(any(String.class), any(String.class));
```

Now, set this `spyUtils` object via setter. Each time `createLink` is invoked, it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can either mock you utils method to do nothing (with PowerMockito) or change you code so utils method is not static and you can inject the mock instance of utils method to the object you test, something like this:

```
class ForTesting{

     UtilsClass utilsInstance;

      ForTesting (UtilsClass utilsInstance) {
        this.utilsInstance = utilsInstance;
      }

     // method you test
      public String doSomeTask(String src, String dst) {
         // some code
             utilsInstance.createLink(src, dst);
          // some more code
      } 
   }

 @Test
 public void test(){
     UtilsClass utilsInstance  = mock(UtilsClass.class);
     ForTesting classForTesting = new ForTesting(utilsInstance);
     assertEquals("yourValue",classForTesting.doSomeTask());

 }
```

Mocking with PowerMockito gives some overhead, because you cant override static methods without inheritance, so some native methods needed to modify byte code at runtime.