# Skipping a method execution using Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, spy

I’m using Mockito for unit testing and I want to skip the execution of a method.

I referred to this ticket [Skip execution of a line using Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55542010/skip-execution-of-a-line-using-mockito). Here, I assume doSomeTask() and createLink() methods are in different classes. But in my case, both the methods are in the same class (ActualClass.java).

```
//Actual Class

public class ActualClass{
    
    //The method being tested
    public void method(){
        //some business logic
        validate(param1, param2);

        //some business logic
    }

    public void validate(arg1, arg2){
        //do something
    }
}

//Test class

public class ActualClassTest{

    @InjectMocks
    private ActualClass actualClassMock;

    @Test
    public void test_method(){

        ActualClass actualClass = new ActualClass();
        ActualClass spyActualClass = Mockito.spy(actualClass);

        // validate method creates a null pointer exception, due to some real time data fetch from elastic

        doNothing().when(spyActualClass).validate(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any());
        actualClassMock.method();
    }
}
```

Since there arises a null pointer exception when the validate method is executed, I’m trying to skip the method call by spying the ActualClass object as stated in the ticket I mentioned above. Still, the issue is not resolve. The validate method gets executed and creates a null pointer exception due to which the actual test method cannot be covered.

So, how do I skip the execution of the validate() method that is within the same class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must always use your spy class when calling `method()`.

```
   @Test
    public void test_method(){
        ActualClass spyActualClass = Mockito.spy(actualClassMock);

        doNothing().when(spyActualClass).validate(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any());
        spyActualClass.method();
    }
```

In practice, instead of

```
actualClassMock.method();
```

you must use

```
spyActualClass.method();
```

Answer (score 2):

In case of any external dependencies the following two annotations can be used at once.
@InjectMocks
@Spy
This will actually spy the original method.
If the method you want to skip exists in some other file, annotate the object of the class with @Spy in which the method to be skipped exists.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).